# QGIS Polygonize not working on large dataset

Tags: qgis, polygonize

I have a 1.3 gigabyte shapefile I am trying to run through the vector polygonizer in QGIS. The lines intersect each other yet when I run it through it gives me "No polygons were created." Is there something wrong with the data?  I am using [Geofabrik data](http://download.geofabrik.de/asia/china.html) for Chinese roads. If I select part of the data it runs fine, so I'm wondering if it's just too much for the tool.

Comment: GDAL polygonize tool is for raster. Do you mean the QGIS Vector geometry - Polygonize tool?

Comment: Oops, yes i did. Edited.

Comment: You seem to tell that it does work with a small dataset but what is the limit?

Comment: I have used 100-250MB files with it before and it works fine.